# VBA: run macro to manipulate a pivot on values in 3 different drop down cells

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am relatively new to VBA.

I have a `PivotTable` summing the data from another Excel sheet. It has 3 data fields: `fees`, `items` and `volume` for companies from ”a” to ”i”. The pivot has also 2 report filters (scheme and category).

Now what I basically need to do is to run following macros depending on values in the dropdown:

1. set the filter in the ”scheme” report filter depending on the value in the respective dropdown
2. delete all the rows in the pivot except the company from the respective dropdown
3. delete the data fields in the pivot except the one mentioned in the respective drop-down.

I found solutions for setting filters in pivot, for deleting the rows and deleting/adding data fields. My problem is to make it work depending on the dropdowns.

I also found the solution for making it work on one drop-down. The question I have is how to approach the problem with 3 drop/downs?

Thanks in advance, any help would be really appreciated!

[[image: This image should show what I am attempting to do:]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the scheme and company fields an easy way to do this without vba is to either simply use slicers,  or use a separate pivot connected to the first via a slicer that has nothing but those two fields in it as page fields,  because these behave pretty much exactly as drop downs. I've outlined this further at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/16/sync-pivots-from-dropdown/. In fact is there any reason why you don't simply add them as page fields on the main pivot and allow users to filter it directly?

Dynamically choosing what to display in the values fields is pretty easy, but I can't post code right now because I'm on holiday without a laptop.  Is there any reason why you don't simply show both? The user can simply ignore the one they don't need. Plus it saves them from having to use the drop down in the event that they want to see both.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with Slicer. I probably overcomplicated the task I had. One last question: is there a way to add multiple selections for the slicer? I added the Slicer but the problem is that I can select only one company at once. Thanks a lot!